# Nginx- Setting up Firewall Bypass Prevention

Tags: nginx, firewall, configuration

I would like to Set up Firewall Bypass Prevention in my Nginx. To do so, I want to add the following directive to Nginx configuration:

```
location / {
    allow xxx.xx.xxx.x/xx;
    allow xxx.xx.xxx.x/xx;;
    allow xxxx:xxxx::/xx;
    allow xx.xxx.xxx.x/xx;
    allow xxx.xxx.x.x/xx;
    deny all;
    # Existing NGINX rules
}
```

I have already got location directive  under server directive as follow:

```
location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }
```

The question is, do I need to add a new location directive for Firewall Bypass Prevention, or I have to append Firewall Bypass Prevention in existing location as following:

```
location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
        allow xxx.xx.xxx.x/xx;
        allow xxx.xx.xxx.x/xx;;
        allow xxxx:xxxx::/xx;
        allow xx.xxx.xxx.x/xx;
        allow xxx.xxx.x.x/xx;
        deny all;
       # Existing NGINX rules
    }
```

Any thought?

Answer (score 1):

You most likely want to move `allow` and `deny` directive to the outside of any `location` and place directly within `server {}`. Then it will be applied to all locations.